# I tried to redirect the url path to the detail view in django

Tags: django-views

I am new in django. I want to redirect the url into the detail view but the path in urls.py is not working.

**this is urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),
path('<school.id>', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
]
```

**this is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (View, TemplateView,
                              DetailView, ListView)
from . import models


class IndexView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'index.html'


class SchoolListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'schools'
model = models.School


class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
context_object_name = 'school_detail'
model = models.School
template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

**this is my school_list.html**

```
{% extends 'basic_app/basic_app_base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<title> School List Page </title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h1> Welcome to the list of schools </h1>
<ol>
{% for school in schools %}
<h3><li><a href="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</a></li></h3>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endblock content %}
```

**this is my school_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'basic_app/basic_app_base.html' %}
{% block title %}
<title> School Details Page </title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h1> Welcome to the Details of schools </h1>
<h2> School Details </h2>
<p>Name: {{school_detail.name}} </p>
<p>Principal: {{school_detail.principal}} </p>
<p>Location: {{school_detail.location}} </p>
<h2> Students: </h2>
{% for student in school_detail.students.all %}
<p> {{student.name}} who is {{student.age}} years old </p>
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

I want to redirect the link into the school detail view.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?

Comment: path('<school.id>', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
] -- this path is not working. I m trying to create path for detail view